# How to login to McMaster-Carr API

Tags: json, authentication, postman, pfx

I am a beginner trying to log in to McMaster-Carr API. I have a .pfx authentication file, an API password, and my main login/password (email/account password). I have imported the .json file into postman and have inputted my main login credentials in the fields below, but I am not getting a success output message. I am confused as to where the API key/password goes and where I upload the .pfx file as well.

[image]

McMaster-Carr API: https://www.mcmaster.com/help/api/

Comment: are you able to provide the error output you are now getting ?

Comment: Hi so I have the certificate working properly, but now when I try to send a login request, I get error 401 "Login Failed". I am unsure as what to put for my username/password in the "body" section for the Log in tab. I have tried my McMaster website login email paired with both the website login password and the Api password, but both seem to give me the same "error 401 login failed". Additionally, there is an authorization page that asks for an authorization type. By default it is set to "No Auth". Is this what is possibly causing the issue?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c86aa78aafdf015c843241e0f0c96f79

Comment: I don't think there is anything that you are doing that is incorrect. I would contact McMaster to confirm that you are using the correct credentials. If there is still an issue, then log it with them.

Comment: I finally figured this out. Quick question - is it possible to do wat i am doing in postman but in python?

Comment: What was your solution @Kaevonz?

Answer (score 0):

### How to upload .pfx file to Postman application

> **[ Windows / Linux ]** - Select *File > Settings > Certificates*
> **[ Mac    ]** - Select *Postman > Preferences > Certificates*

[image: Settings / Preferences screen]

> On the *Client Certificates* section, select the *Add Certificate* link
> Add the hostname domain of the API service: *api.mcmaster.com*
> Upload the .pfx file
> Add the passphrase for the .pfx file: *API password*

[image: Adding API Cert Config]

> Select *Add* (details should appear as below)
> Close the screen and try to log in again with the same request

[image: API Cert Config saved]

Comment: Hi so I have the certificate working properly, but now when I try to send a login request, I get error 401 "Login Failed". I am unsure as what to put for my username/password in the "body" section for the Log in tab. I have tried my McMaster website login email paired with both the website login password and the Api password, but both seem to give me the same "error 401 login failed". Additionally, there is an authorization page that asks for an authorization type. By default it is set to "No Auth". Is this what is possibly causing the issue?

Comment: Basically, what do I put for username/password here https://gyazo.com/c86aa78aafdf015c843241e0f0c96f79